# ReactJS mixed all css

Tags: reactjs

First page is `Index.js` and contains `Index.css`

**Path->** `/src/action/Index.js`

```
- src
|
-- action
|
--- Index.js

import '../css/Index.css';
```

Second page is `Customer.js` contains `Auth.css`

**Path->** `/src/action/User/Customer.js`

```
- src
|
-- action
|
--- User
|
---- Customer.js

import '../../css/Auth.css';
```

The problem is that both pages are using both CSS files. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you considered using css modules?

Comment: Post better source example to make clear question. Did you use webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Those CSS files become global when imported like that. The easiest way is to add classNames to your component like this:

```
<ComponentA className="a">
```

Then in corresponding CSS file target the class:

```
.a {
  color: red;
}
```

In reality you might want to get to know CSS-in-JS solutions like styled-components or learn automatic hashing for CSS with webpack. Check this tutorial for example: https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-style-react-components-in-2019-30f1ccc2b5b

Comment: Not clear, where you add `className` ? and how can separate two css file with a classname ?

Comment: `Not clear, where you add className` > like in html, as attribute - 
`How can separate two css file with a classname` > create two css files and import them in JS files

Answer (score 0):

Your index.css module should import a "tree" of relevant css modules, using @import "example.css".
I'd recomment to nest it more, to different css modules that import other css themselves, creating a logical tree of css imports. 
Using that, the only import you'll need to do is to the root index css.